# Is it possible to have a list children for <meta-data> in manifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I need to store a list of values for my custom attribute:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application>
        <meta-data android:name="listOfAttributes" >
            <item
                name="xx1"
                value="yy1"/>
            <item
                name="xx2"
                value="yy2"/>
            <item
                name="xx3"
                value="yy3"/>
        </meta-data>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Is it possible? And how I can get values from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible?

No. Have it point to an XML resource instead, the way you see done with app widget provider metadata, search metadata, device admin metadata, etc. That way, you can have an arbitrarily-complex structure in the XML.

You can read more about this in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html).

Comment: I'm trying to have all information in the manifest.xml avoiding a resource loading. That's ok, is not possible. Thanks.